# Validate Form Field using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I've a form field with one input field.

As soon as the user completes typing i need to make an ajax call and validate input on serverside.

I tired keyup, focusout, keydown and mouseup events but doesn't seem to work as expected. Could some one please suggest the best keyboard events to choose to resolve this. If the input is blank the error message should be shown as well.

Comment: I would suggest to use try client side validation.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery validation on the page itself http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

Comment: You left out `keypress` event :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you are probably looking for is the blur() event, which is called when the user
leaves an input field (by pressing tab, or clicking on the next input for example)

Example:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input#myInput').blur(function(){
            myValidator($(this), $(this).val());
        });
    });

    function myValidator($element, value)
    {
        // Example regex to sucessfully match a value of at least 4 digits
        if (!value.match(/^[0-9]{4,}$/)
        {
            // In this case I'm adding an error class to the input,
            // but feel free to do anything you like
            $element.addClass('error');
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Validating via AJAX is VERY bad practice, as one could easily stop the HTTP request or disable JavaScript entirely (and personally I try to avoid unnecessary http requests).

I recommend first checking client side (JavaScript/jQuery only), and when submitted double check server-side (with PHP/ASP).

Answer (score 0):

The onchange event might be what you need.

onchange listens for any change made in the value of an input element, whereas the key events register only actions performed on the keyboard ( Pressing and releasing Esc is also a valid trigger for example ).

However I really don't get the actual question here. I think that what you're looking for is a **regular expression**.

Regular expressions are patterns that can be used to check whether data satisfies the conditions given. For example:

```
'/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{5, 10}/'
```

Which may be used to determine a text is only Alphanumeric and between 5 and 10 chars in length. It also allows hypens ( - ) in this case.

Information about this may be found anywhere on the web.

Also, think aboout posting you're question a bit more descriptive and adding a sample of the code you're using. This will probably inspire more helpful answers.

Kind Regards,

D.

Answer (score 0):

I will show an example page and make it correct into your page code....

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
* { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 96%; }
label { width: 10em; float: left; }
label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
p { clear: both; }
.submit { margin-left: 12em; }
em { font-weight: bold; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cemail" name="email" size="25"  class="required email" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <em>  </em><input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="ccomment">Your comment</label>
     <em>*</em><textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" cols="22"  class="required"></textarea>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can take much more concepts from here : http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/landau/zKrYS/

I'm not quite sure what "doesn't work as expected means", but here is an example.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("input").val().trim();
    if (!val) {
        alert("please fill in the field");
        return;
    }
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
            value: val
        },
        type: "post"
    }).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data, status, xhr);
    });
});​
```